# Filter columns using column from another table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframe, a small one with IDs and a large one (6 billion rows with id and trx_id). I want all the transactions from the large table that have the same customer ID as the small one. For example:

df1:

```
+------+
|userid|
+------+
|   348|
|   567|
|   595|
+------+
```

df2:

```
+------+----------+
|userid|  trx_id  |
+------+----------+
|   348|       287|
|   595|       288|
|   348|       311|
|   276|       094|
|   595|       288|
|   148|       512|
|   122|       514|
|   595|       679|
|   567|       870|
|   595|       889|
+------+----------+
```

Result I want:

```
+------+----------+
|userid|  trx_id  |
+------+----------+
|   348|       287|
|   595|       288|
|   348|       311|
|   595|       288|
|   595|       679|
|   567|       870|
|   595|       889|
+------+----------+
```

Should I use a join or filter? If so which command?

Comment: Do `df1.join(df2,"userid")`

Comment: is that faster than filter and spark sql?

Comment: @user1871528 Added some more information to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the small dataframe can fit into memory, you can do a broadcast join. That means that the small dataframe will be broadcasted to all executor nodes and the subsequent join can be done efficiently without any shuffle.

You can hint that a dataframe should be broadcasted using `broadcast`:

```
df2.join(broadcast(df1), "userid", "inner")
```

Note that the `join` method is called on the larger dataframe.

---

If the first dataframe is even smaller (~100 rows or less), `filter` would be a viable, faster, option. The idea is to collect the dataframe and convert it to a list, then use `isin` to filter the large dataframe. This should be faster as long as the data is small enough.

```
val userids = df1.as[Int].collect()
df2.filter($"userid".isin(userids:_*))
```